# REACT app not starting in command prompt\

Tags: reactjs, npm, command-prompt

i have been trying to start react app on npm but it is not running[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moNDW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same promlem, if there is a cache folder or a folder like .next or .parcel depending on what builder you are using, delete the cache and try again. Also hit npm run build after deleting the cache and then npm start.
If you want to start in dev mode just hit npm run dev after cleaning the cache

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run `npm install` to install the dependencies before you run `npm start`

Comment: I have tried it and it worked hoping more from you